Error while I try to start keycloak server v -18.0.2
I'm downloaded from here https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/tag/18.0.2
and unzip it. After trying to run a script kc.bat start-dev i get an exception
C:\keycloak\keycloak-18.0.2\bin>kc.bat start-dev Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
I saw a solution like replace : to ; in 127 line I want to try it but there is not : in line 127
How can i fix this issue? and what causes this issue?

Can you try v18.0.2 by docker compose?
